# How to get the results of dataframe appended to a single csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a dataset with 5 columns from which the 2-column, 3-column and 4-column combinations are retrieved using the below code. I would like to get all these results in a single csv file. I'm new to using lists- can anyone help me with this.

```
df2 =[df[list(pair)] for pair in list(iter.combinations(df.columns, 2))]
df3 =[df[list(pair)] for pair in list(iter.combinations(df.columns, 3))]
df4 =[df[list(pair)] for pair in list(iter.combinations(df.columns, 4))]
```

I tried using the below but getting an exception that lists doesn't have an attribute to_csv

```
df2.to_csv(export_file, mode = 'w', index=False)
df3.to_csv(export_file, mode = 'a', index=False)
df4.to_csv(export_file, mode = 'a', index=False)
```

Expected results would be to get all the results of df2, df3 and df4 appended in a single csv file.

Comment: `df2` is a `list`. `list` objects do not have a `.to_csv` methods. It seems you think that `df2` is actually a `pandas.DataFrame` object, but it is not. You are assigning to it the results of a list-comprehension, which will always evaluate to a `list`

Comment: As an aside, calling `list` on the result of your `itertools.combinations` objects is unecessary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your response. Can this be achieved without using list comprehension so that I can pull the results in a csv file

Comment: @Ramesh: Create a **empty** `df` and do `df.append(<df2, df3, df4>)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your help